# Three column <DIV> navigation bar, based on center <DIV>'s width

Tags: css, layout, html, navigation

What I am trying to accomplish is a navigation bar that is center-aligned, padded on both sides with a left and right padding div.

The actual navigation bar is currently an inline-block div containing my  tags for links and a left and right transition image, which will lead into the background of the navigation bar to take up the remaining space.

Normally, I would center the navigation bar in a 100% width div and use that wide div as the background, but since I am using semi-transparent .png files, I can't overlap like that.

The layout I would like:

[image: Image of layout showing the three DIVs]

*[(Click image to view full size.)](http://i28.tinypic.com/3451y6c.png)*

I updated this question to include an actual image of what I am working with. Currently I set the three `<div>`s (Technically, the center is a `<UL>`) to fixed widths, but I would like to add the flexibility of adding/removing links, and it will expand and shrink the `<div>`s accordingly. As I said earlier, I cannot center-align the center links and overlap them on the background because I am using semitransparent `.png` files for the images.

Answer (score 1):

Fact is, you do not need the padding `<div>`. All you need to do is specify an `auto` horizontal margin, which will automatically expand to grab all the space available (thus centering your content as a side-effect).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #header-nav {
        width: 100%;
      }

      #header-nav-items {
        margin: 0 auto; /* auto centers */
      }

      #header-nav-items a {
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #f00;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header-nav">
      <div id="header-nav-items">
        <a href="#">We are centered!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: great (short and sweet) explanation of what "auto" margin actually does. +1

Comment: This does not center the text since the inner div is a block filling the entire width of the parent block.

Comment: @Gert G: true, forgot to give a width to `#header-nav-items` corrected.

Comment: A fair enough answer, and I've known about the margin: 0 auto; technique, I use it quite frequently. But I _DO_ want two divs or spans to fill the left and right space so I can add the background of the menu. Think a horizontal white bar, in which I want to cut into the middle to add the links. As I mentioned before, I can not have any overlap, or this would be a simple operation.

Comment: @Billy... check out my answer. I think it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I completed the layout using a 3-column table instead. I did *not* specify a width for the left and right cells and I specified the center cell's width as 0. The center cell stretches to fill the content, and pushes the right two cells away.

Anybody know of any problems with this?